# Unicode String reading

Tags: java

Hi, I have a Java application that reads data from the console and prints it.

If I enter a Unicode String in the Console, for example \u06F1, it is printing \u06F1 instead of "?".

What change should I make in the code to display the character as "?".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should do the following

- use a regex to find all occurrences of the following:

  \u[0-9a-fA-F]{4};
- Then you should use `Integer.parseInt()` on the numeric portion;
- finally you should replace the string with the integer cast to a char.

Does this make sense to you?